# Better way than multiple subquery for the same table but different criteria in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgres-9.6

For example, I might have a schema like:
[image: schema]

And I am trying to get something, that is like:

```
| inventory_id | all_paid_merchandise_quantity | all_shipped_merchandise_quantity |
|--------------|-------------------------------|----------------------------------|
| 1            | 10                            | 100                              |
| 2            | 11                            | 12                               |
```

I've already came up with something like a subquery for `all_paid_merchandise_quantity`, and another one for `all_shipped_merchandise_quantity`. But I wonder if there's a better way to do this?

edit: the "ugly" query.

```
SELECT
    inventory.id AS inventory_id,
    (SELECT sum(order_items.quantity) FROM "order" LEFT JOIN "order_items" ON order_items.order_id="order".id WHERE "order".has_shipped=true AND "order_items".merchandise_id=merchandise.id) AS all_shipped_merchandise_quantity,
    (SELECT sum(order_items.quantity) FROM "order" LEFT JOIN "order_items" ON order_items.order_id="order".id WHERE "order".has_paid=true AND "order_items".merchandise_id=merchandise.id) AS all_paid_merchandise_quantity
FROM 
    inventory
LEFT JOIN merchandise ON merchandise.inventory_id=inventory.id
GROUP BY inventory.id, merchandise.id
ORDER BY inventory.id
```

Comment: Can you share the query you have so far?

Comment: Yes. I have edited the question and added the query.

Comment: Use outer joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
    inventory.id AS inventory_id,
    merchandise.id AS merchandise_id,
    sum(order_items.quantity) FILTER (WHERE "order".has_shipped) AS all_shipped_merchandise_quantity,
    sum(order_items.quantity) FILTER (WHERE "order".has_paid) AS all_paid_merchandise_quantity
FROM 
    inventory
LEFT JOIN merchandise ON merchandise.inventory_id=inventory.id
LEFT JOIN "order_items" ON "order_items".merchandise_id=merchandise.id
LEFT JOIN "order" ON (order_items.order_id="order".id AND ("order".has_shipped OR "order".has_paid))
GROUP BY inventory.id, merchandise.id
ORDER BY inventory.id
```

Comment: @esfy PS: Be careful because `FILTER` does not actually filtering out the rows but just not taking in account rows that not corresponds to the filter condition what would to cause the performance issues. Added appropriate filtering to the `JOIN` condition (see changes in the answer).